# Prometheus metrics : How to differentiate http_server_requests_seconds_count metrics '2xx' among '200', '201', '206' etc

Tags: spring-boot, rest, prometheus, monitoring, metrics

For my spring boot Rest API, I am using prometheus metrics for application monitoring.
My Rest API can give http response code 200 OK or 201 CREATED or 206 - Partial Content etc.
In my Prometheus endpoint "/actuator/prometheus" , I am only getting one metrics with 2xx *(combining data for 200, 201 and 206)* as below,

```
http_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="POST",status="2xx",uri="/myTestAPI",quantile="0.95",} 2.33
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="POST",status="2xx",uri="/myTestAPI",} 312.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="POST",status="2xx",uri="/myTestAPI",} 780.701046969
```

Is there a way to get these metrics per http code like one for '200', one for '201' etc?